# AggregateException - What does AggregateException.Flatten().InnerException represent?

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, task

I've been looking at some code in one of our applications that looks as follows:

```
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
    this._logger.Log(ae.Flatten().InnerException.ToString(), Category.Exception, Priority.High);
}
```

My question is this. I know what `AggregateException.Flatten()` does, and I know what `AggregateException.Flatten().InnerExceptions` represents. However, what does `AggregateException.Flatten().InnerException` (single) represent?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It will just be *one* of the non-AggregateExceptions within the original exception. So for example, if you have an initial `AggregateException` of:

```
AggregateException
    AggregateException
        IOException("x")
        IOException("y")
    IOException("z")
```

Then the `InnerException` of the flattened result would come out as either `IOException("x")`, `IOException("y")` or `IOException("z")`. I don't believe there's any guarantee about *which* it would be. (I believe the current behaviour would give the "z" version at the moment...) It will be the first of the `InnerExceptions` on the flattened version, but that should be seen as a *union* of all the original non-AggregateExceptions, with no guaranteed order.

Basically `InnerException` isn't terribly useful for `AggregateException`. It would be far more useful to log *all* the `InnerExceptions`... or just call `ToString()` on the top-level exception, which would keep all the structure...